# Express and node app returns error

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following server.js file for my react application:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('src/client/'));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'))
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server started');
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script src="bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I hit "http://localhost:8080/" the screen is blank and I have a console error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <) however I can easily access all of the css and js files. 
If I hit "http://localhost:8080/css/style.css" I can see the stylesheet.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your index.html file.

Comment: see updated....

Comment: What is the result when you type `curl http://localhost:8080` in the command line?

Comment: Failed to connect localhost:8080 Connection refused

Comment: Try to open `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` - probably you want here to serve JS instead of *index.html*. Have you created *bundle.js* on `src/client` directory?

Comment: How would I do that, sorry I am new to express, could point me to the right direction? Thanks

Comment: I have updated the routes... Problem solved, thank you

Comment: Did you get the slick carousel working for your express app? I can't seem to get mine to work. I've done the two simple steps of linking the css and adding the script from the cdn.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the following:

from

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'))
});
```

to

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/client/index.html'))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> if you want to redirect to other file then do like that and will render signup.html when u call like `"http://localhost:8080/signup`

```
var app   = require('express')();
app.get('/signup',function(req,res){

 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/src/client/signup.html'));});
```

> if you want to home page mean get request from same directory do like that so this will render when request like this `"http://localhost:8080/`

```
var app   = require('express')();
app.get('/',function(req,res){

 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/src/client/index.html'));});
```